# write out values to pipe between python and lua script

Tags: python-3.x, lua, pipe

I am writing a program which utilises lua script and python script.

I am calling python script from within lua as:

```
-- lua
pipe = io.popen("python3 main.py", "w")
```

Now, when the python executes code I want to do something like this:

```
# python
sys.stdout.write(str(timevar))
```

The problem is that the timevar is being sent to the Linux terminal and I cannot catch it in pipe inside lua script with:

```
-- lua
result = pipe:read("*a")
```

Hence, how to send data via pipe? I am reading from the pipe with:

```
#python
import fileinput
info = [ line[:-1] for line in fileinput.input() ]
```

which works well, but writing to output does not, so I am not sure if I made a mistake somewhere or does the python ask for something else to be done?

Comment: You may find it easier to call lua from python. Python is often the better "glue" language.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I cannot go the other way around (too complicated why). And the lack of documentation on lua's pipe is extremely troublesome, but that is the way I have to go. -.-

Comment: `io.popen` can open pipe either to read or to write, but not both. So to read you have to use `r` modificator or use some other library to do bidirectional IO.

Comment: @Amaterastis `print(str(timevar))` should allow lua to see the output.

Comment: I tried openning it as: io.popen("python3 main.py", "w") and io.popen("python3 main.py", "r"), but it completely shuts down the "write" pipe. Thanks though. I thought there could've been an argument for bidirectional IO.

Comment: @fcbsd, both print() and sys.stdout.write() will leave trace on the terminal. I do not want to show anything there.

Comment: @Amaterastis - To hide output on the terminal `io.popen("python3 main.py >/dev/null 2>&1", "w")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks! :) Are there any documentation on io.popen for lua?

Comment: @Amaterastis - [D](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) [O](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) [C](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks! :) I was not able to find it myself. :(